# Remove gutters from TabControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

Im writing a user drawn TabControl. The class inherits from the base TabControl class and for some reason I can't get rid of this ugly gutter. I want the TabPage to span the entire width of the control. Do I need to draw my own TabPage?

Comment: A gutter on the right hand side?  What are you talking about?  Screen shot required.

Comment: SCREENSHOT:
http://yfrog.com/g0niggitydigdangj

Comment: the black crap around the tab page. do i have to change the location and size that the tab page renders to? i want it to still be dockable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what aspect of the TabControl you're talking about, but I assume that it's either the Padding attribute or the Margin attribute since there is no "gutter" attribute. Setting the values in one of those fields to zero will most likely accomplish what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: This doesn't work with a default-drawn tab control. I do not know if it works with the specific owner drawn tab control the OP is using.